# Trying to create a dropdown menu inside a table that stays after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this menu inserted into a table and i want that after i click a cell from a table appears the second menu hidden but everytime i click the second menu appears and disapears.

I want that everytime i click "menu1" or "menu" shows the option inside of the "second nav" that is inside the "menu1" or "menu2". Also when it shows i want them to stay there and when i click again it disapears. See snippet to better understand what im trying to accomplish.

```js
$(".menu1").on('click',function () {
   $(".second nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
});
$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

// menu 2
 $(".menu2").on('click',function () {
   $('.nav').$('li div ul').toggle('');
});

$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

// menu 3
 $(".menu3").on('click',function () {
   $(".nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
});

$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

// menu 4
 $(".menu4").on('click',function () {
   $(".nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
});

$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

// menu 5
 $(".menu5").on('click',function () {
   $(".nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
});

$('.nav > li div ul li a').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
tr{
 color: black;
}
* { margin:0;
padding:0;
}
h1{
 color:Black;
}
.close{display:none;}

li.menu1{
 background-color: orange;
}
li.menu2{
 background-color: orange;
}
li.menu3{
 background-color: orange;
}
li.menu4{
 background-color: orange;
}
li.menu5{
 background-color: orange;
}
/* Första boxarna*/
ul.nav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
 z-index:0;
 color: orange;

    -webkit-background-size: 50% 100%;
 display: list-item;
 font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
 font-size: 18px;
    
}

li {
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

ul.nav li a  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 15px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px #888;
}

ul.nav li a:hover {
    color: #67a5cd;
    padding: 9px 15px 7px 30px;
}
ul.nav li ul { 
display:none;
}
ul.nav li:active ul { 
display:block;
position:relative;
left:3px;
top:0px;
list-style: none;
z-index:999;
background: orange;
}

ul.nav li ul li
{ 
background:orange;
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

 <h1 strong>Plataforma de Alocações</h1>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/menu.css">

<body>
<table width="200px" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
  <td>Sociedade Construções Manuel Moreira Maia LDA</td>
  </tr>
 <!--menu 1 --> 
<tr>
  <td>
 <ul class="nav">
   <li class="menu1"><a href="#">Alocações</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Nova Alocação</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Listar Alocações</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
   </ul>
 </td>
 </tr>
<!--menu 2 --> 
 <tr> 
  <td>
   <ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu2"><a href="#">Projetos</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Listar Projetos</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
   </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
<!--menu 3 --> 
 <tr>
 <td>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu3"><a href="#">Colaborador</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Adicionar Colaborador</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Listar Colaboradores</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
  </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <!--menu 4 --> 
 <tr>
 <td>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu4"><a href="#">Meios de Transporte</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Adicionar veículo</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Listar Veículos</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
  </ul>
  </td>
 </tr>
    <!--menu 5 --> 
    <tr>
 <td>
     <ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu5"><a href="#">Prestadores de Serviçoes</a>
   <div class="second nav">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Adicionar Novo Prestador</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Listar Prestador de Serviços</a></li>
     </ul></div></li>
  </ul>
  
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
 <script src="JS/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="JS/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript code, the class selector is not correct:

```
$(".second nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
```

must be

```
$(".second.nav").$('li div ul').toggle('');
```

since the "nav" is a second class of the tag, not the "nav" html component

I created a fiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/52977/